# SSRS 2016 - Web Portal URL and Web Service URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

Is it possible to customize web portal URL instead of just machine name ?

I tried add in custom settings of configuration manager as shown in below screen shot - after making localhost entry - I am still having issues. I get service is not available error. I tried to configure web service url also same, but with that not able to access web service URL

[image: Your Image]

Trying to see if anyone successful configuring SSRS web portal to custom URL instead of default one `<machineName>/Reports`

Comment: You are doing fine, but I guess that the problem is that the name `localreports.com` can't be resolved to an IP address. You will have to also take care for *name resolution*, for example using a DNS entry. Ask your network admins to create one for you. Also: when changing the TCP port from 80 to something else (like 82), you will have to specify that in the web browser when accessing the portal, just like shown as URL at the bottom of the dialog box.

Comment: added localreports.com to my local host file, the name resolution seems fine. I just figured out the issue, for the portal URL I had .com and for service URL I missed .com in the URL after I added .com in both places it worked fine, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that, so "happy reporting"! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the issue, for the portal URL I had .com and for service URL I missed .com in the URL after I added .com in both places it worked fine.

In the SSRS configuration manager both Web Portal URL and Service Portal URL should be the same

Comment: Please mark your answer as "solution", so others can take advantage of it when having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I have the exact problem. However, when I access the page after setting the host header, it's asking for a user name and password. I wonder what user name and password it's asking for. Any suggestion?

Comment: @2myCharlie, Please try with your Windows login credentials